# Adding and removing numbers from the total box onchange

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add and remove the price when the check box is checked and unchecked. I am using an event listener function but it is not working how I want it to. How will I be able to click on either of the check boxes to add to the total and remove when unchecked?

HTML:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  'use strict';

  const form = document.getElementById('orderForm');

  form.addEventListener("change", function() {

    var total = 0;
    const checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]');
    const checkboxCount = checkboxes.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxCount; i++) {

      const checkbox = checkboxes[i];

      if (checkbox.checked) {

        total += parseFloat(checkbox.dataset.price);

        form.total.value = total;

        var boxTotal = parseFloat(total);

        boxTotal = boxTotal.toFixed(2);

        form.total.value = boxTotal;

      } else {

        form.total.value -= this.value;
      }
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<form id="orderForm">
  <section id="selectRecords">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">10.80</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" data-price="9.80"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">15.70</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" data-price="12.70"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">18.20</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" data-price="8.20"></span>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="checkCost">
    Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly="">
  </section>

  </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're summing up all checkboxes associated prices on `change`, you shouldn't have the `} else { form.total.value -= this.value;` - not only does `this` refer to the `form` (which doesn't have a `.value`), you also don't care at all about the unchecked prices, because they don't affect final value after a `change` event anyway.

You can select only the checked checkboxes in your query string with the `:checked` psuedo-selector - this will let you leave out the `if (checkbox.checked)` part.

You also might consider coming up with the total number *once*, and then assigning to the `input`'s value *once*, rather than on every iteration:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('orderForm');

form.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let total = 0;
  const checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]:checked');
  const checkboxCount = checkboxes.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxCount; i++) {
    const checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    total += Number(checkbox.dataset.price);
  }
  form.total.value = total.toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<form id="orderForm">
  <section id="selectRecords">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">10.80</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" value="973" data-price="9.80"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">15.70</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" value="974" data-price="12.70"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">18.20</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" value="975" data-price="8.20"></span>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="checkCost">
    Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly="">
  </section>

  </section>
</form>
```

Also, to be a bit more functional, you might use `Array.prototype.reduce` to calculate the `total`, rather than a `for` loop:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('orderForm');

form.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const total = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
    form.querySelectorAll('input[data-price][type=checkbox]:checked'),
    (a, checkbox) => a + Number(checkbox.dataset.price),
    0
  );
  form.total.value = total.toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<form id="orderForm">
  <section id="selectRecords">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">10.80</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" value="973" data-price="9.80"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">15.70</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" value="974" data-price="12.70"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="price">18.20</span>
      <span class="chosen"><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" value="975" data-price="8.20"></span>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="checkCost">
    Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly="">
  </section>

  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Array.prototype.reduce` and similar methods (`map`, `forEach`...) are significantly slower than a `for` loop. Of course, for such a small number of items as in this example, it shouldn't matter, but when the arrays are large (for example, a 500x500 cellular automaton matrix), it has a huge performance impact.

Comment: Sure, if iterating over 250000 items, a `for` loop will be the best choice, but unless one is working with unreasonably huge arrays, it's probably better to prefer clean, functional, abstract code over `for` loops (no abstraction, require manual iteration, code intent is usually less clear at a glance)